# Convert column name to var name

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, tidyr

I have two data frames (df1 & df2). one data frame has only one column with 1000 rows, and the second data frame has 1000 columns. I want to make the df1 column 1 row content into var name for df2. Default names is there for df1/2 V1, V2....

Here are the examples:

```
df1
V1
a
b
c
d

df2
V1   V2  V3
a1   b1  c1
a2   b2  c2
a3   b3  c3
```

Final output should look like this

```
df3
a   b   c
a1  b1  c1
a2  b2  c2
a3  b3  c3

names(df3)
"a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: have a look at `?colnames` (so `colnames(df2) <- df1$V1`, except, here, `df2` is missing a "d" so `df1$V1[1:ncol(df2)]`)

Answer (score 0):

Set the names() of df2 to the vector of df1:

```
df3 <- df2
names(df3) <- df1$V1
```

Assumes the rows of df1 and columns of df2 are the same length.

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed it!
colnames(df2) <- df1$V1